# Using perspective projection yields incorrect results

Tags: 3d, affinetransform, gl-matrix, transformation-matrix

I use [gl-matrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/tree/master/docs) JS library to transform points in 3d. When I use model-view matrix (`lookAt`), the transformed points make sense.

But when I add perspective projection on top of that, the resulting transformed points do not make much sense (the values of the coordinates have ridiculously small values). What do I do wrong?

```
  // four points on a square
  const points = [
    vec3.fromValues(  0,   0, 0),
    vec3.fromValues(200,   0, 0),
    vec3.fromValues(  0, 200, 0),
    vec3.fromValues(200, 200, 0),
  ]

  points.forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log("point", i, p)
  })

  // look from the center above the points towards the center between the points
  const viewer = vec3.fromValues(100, 100, 200)
  const lookat = vec3.fromValues(100, 100,   0)
  const mv = mat4.create()
  mat4.lookAt(mv, viewer, lookat, vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0))

  const transformed_points = [
    vec3.create(),
    vec3.create(),
    vec3.create(),
    vec3.create(),
  ]

  points.forEach(function(p, i) {
    vec3.transformMat4(transformed_points[i], p, mv)
  })

  // the points transformed through model-view matrix make sense, the center is (0,0)
  // and the four points are +/- 100 around the center
  transformed_points.forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log("point mv", i, p)
  })

  const p = mat4.create()
  const mvp = mat4.create()
  // then adding perspective to the model-view-perspective matris, the values
  // of the transformed points are riducuously small, like +/-0.5
  mat4.perspective(p, Math.PI/2, 1 /* aspect */, 100 /* near */, 1000 /* far */)
  mat4.multiply(mvp, p, mv)

  points.forEach(function(p, i) {
    vec3.transformMat4(transformed_points[i], p, mvp)
  })

  transformed_points.forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log("point mvp", i, p)
  })
```

The result is as follows:

```
// those are the original points on a square
point 0   [ 0, 0, 0 ]
point 1   [ 200, 0, 0 ]
point 2   [ 0, 200, 0 ]
point 3   [ 200, 200, 0 ]

// the original points transformed with MV matrix, values make sense
// because the "world" is now centered at the observers eye
point mv 0   [ -100, -100, -200 ]
point mv 1   [ 100, -100, -200 ]
point mv 2   [ -100, 100, -200 ]
point mv 3   [ 100, 100, -200 ]

// when I add the perspective, the transformed points make no sense.
point mvp 0   [ -0.5, -0.5, 0.11111106723546982 ]
point mvp 1   [ 0.5, -0.5, 0.11111106723546982 ]
point mvp 2   [ -0.5, 0.5, 0.11111106723546982 ]
point mvp 3   [ 0.5, 0.5, 0.11111106723546982 ]
```

What I expected is that the points after applying the perspective transformation will still be in some reasonable ~100 range, but not all collapsed in the center of the view around +/- 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that applying perspective projection moves the coordinates to the Clip Space:

https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems

FTR, I fed this question to ChatGPT and I got answers that looked like valid but were only misleading.